# The specified file or folder name is too long

Tags: document-library, file-upload, limitations

I Know by default, file name length is 128 char, but can this be overridden, because I need my file name to be longer then 150 char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the limits imposed by SharePoint which we can't override.

> Character limit for files and folders
>
> These limits apply to files and folders that you add to a synced
>   library folder for uploading to SharePoint. In SharePoint Server 2013,
>   file names can have up to 128 characters. In SharePoint Online, file
>   names can have up to 256 characters. Folder names can have up to 250
>   characters. Folder name and file name combinations can have up to 250
>   characters.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2933738

Comment: Yes, but it's important to keep in mind that your entire URL - including the web URL and path leading up to the actual filename - is limited to 256 characters. Therefore, when using any web-based system, shorter names are always best practice.